# How do I call a function object inside a template class, where the function object uses the templates in the function signature?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, variadic

I'm not sure how to word this question title exactly...

I have a class like this:

```
class HasFuncBase
{
public:
    virtual int GetKey() = 0;
};

template<class... Cs>
class HasFunc : public HasFuncBase
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void(std::vector<Cs>&....)> Func;

    HasFunc(Func func)
    :
        m_func(func)
    {}

    virtual int GetKey() { return id; }

private:
    Func m_func;

    static int id;
};

template<class... Cs>
int HasFunc::id = unique_key_generator<Cs...>::GetKey();
```

I've skipped the `unique_key_generator` for brevity.

Then, another class holds the "data" for m_func above:

```
class HasData
{
public:
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> data;
    int someId;
}
```

Each element in the data vector is the bytes of data for the HasFunc class.

Another class is managing the whole thing:

```
class Manager
{
public:
    std::vector<HasData> m_hadDatas;
    std::vector<HasFuncBase*> m_hasFuncs;
};
```

Now the Manager class needs to find the matching funcs for the matching data and call them. What's really important is that it passes the data as a reference, so that the `HasFunc` will act on the data stored in `HasData`.

```
class Manager
...
    void CallFuncs()
    {
        for(HasFuncBase* f : m_hasFuncs)
        {
            for(HasData& d : m_hasDatas)
            {
                if(d.someId == f->GetKey())
                {
                    /*
                    I need to convert the vector of data vectors
                    in the HasData into function arguments
                    of the right type for HasFunc
                    */
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
```

I know I could add to the HasFunc class a template function like:

```
class HasClass
...
    template<typename... Ts>
    void Execute(std::vector<Ts>&... dataArrays)
    {
        m_func(dataArrays);
    }
...
```

which seems to me to be the way to do it, because `Manager` doesn't know the types of the concrete `HasFuncBase`.

I figure I need some sort of template unpacking trick in `HasClass` that will be called from `Manager` that will then cast the `vector<data>` arrays, after unpacking them, into the above `Execute` function, but I can't see how.

Comment: Add a virtual function to `HasFuncBase` that takes a reference or pointer to `HasData`. Implement that function in `HasFunc`. Make it `HasFunc`'s responsibility to convert the raw data to the right types - it knows the types.

Comment: Okay that makes sense @IgorTandetnik but how do I unpack and cast?

Comment: Unpack what, and cast to what else? I don't know what `Cs` are supposed to be, nor how a `vector<char>` is supposed to turn into an instance of one of them. I assumed you were going to perform some sort of deserialization. Perhaps you could show an example of how this machinery is expected to be used.